# Why does File:/// crash my app?

Tags: macos, crash, bug

Whenever I type `File:///` into the URL bar in Chrome, into Text Edit, and more, it crashes the app. I found out about this after reading [this blog post](http://gizmodo.com/5981370/this-text-string-crashes-almost-any-app-on-a-mac-running-mountain-lion).

How can I avoid this crash and make it impossible for apps that get this string whether it's typed, pasted or arrives in a file, message or download?

Comment: Does it crash the app, or does it crash your system?

Comment: @kojiro: the app. In case of programs like Chrome or text editors, this is a VERY severe bug, seeing as you lose all work.

Comment: I'm not arguing it's not severe, I'm just pointing out that the title and last sentence says *system*, but it does not, in fact, crash your system.

Comment: @kojiro: type it into Spotlight, and it crashes the bar. Yes, not quite a kernel panic, but severe enough to warrant "system" imo.

Comment: Are you more concerned about people typing 8 characters on your computer than you are about them selecting Force Quit or Shutdown from the Apple menu?

Comment: @RussellBorogove The danger is not someone typing on your computer but people sending you a message, mail or document with the text in it. Mail will crash, reopen, crash until you manually delete the file with the *dangerous* content.

Comment: As described, it does indeed crash because of a (rather nasty) bug in 10.8.1/10.8.2. I would like to confirm, for reasons of clarity, that in 10.8.3, it has been fixed. (I am running the beta version - Build 12D68)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a bug in 10.8.1 and 10.8.2 only.

The workaround for this pesky bug is to disable two items in **Language & Text Preference Pane** in System Preferences on affected versions of Mountain Lion:

- Select (click) on Text in the middle towards the top of the window
- deselect (uncheck) "Correct spelling automatically"
- deselect (uncheck) "Use symbol and text substitution"

Credit for this workaround goes to [user shess on the open radar web site](http://openradar.appspot.com/13128709#aglvcGVucmFkYXJyEAsSB0NvbW1lbnQYkZGiAQw).

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if it's a message received in Messages.app

Comment: @Gert Nice - it also won't work in some cases where you get a file with that string (or similar string) embedded in the filesystem and the crash code starts getting fancy with what looks like a URL/URI. I would be astounded if the next security or dot update doesn't squash this high profile bug.

Comment: let's hope so. Just for the record. To fix `Messages.app`, you need to remove your `chat.db` in `~/Library/Messages/`

Answer (score 14):

bmike has the workaround, I'll provide the "why":
According to [this article](http://thenextweb.com/shareables/2013/02/02/typing-these-eight-characters-will-crash-almost-any-application-on-your-mac/) from TheNextWeb, a feature called Data Detectors, which scans text for meaningful formats (dates, locations...) also looks for file URLs. It does this by looking for "file://", case-insensitive. However, later in the procedure, it asserts that the string should start with "file://" lowercase -- and when this is not the case, such as when there is a capital F, it throws an exception, which apparently (and extremely sloppily) brings down the whole application.