# Why do some Unicode text messages crash the iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

Recently a new "glitch" has surfaced over the Internet over the last few weeks where if an iPhone user is sent:

```
  effective. 
      Power
           لُلُصّبُلُلصّبُررً ॣ ॣh ॣ ॣ
 冗
```

**via iMessage** it crashes the phone OS temporarily and force restarts the receiving phone.

Why does this work?

Comment: Actually, I believe only the Arabic characters (and maybe the ones after them) are required. The "effective power" text is just a filler and can be anything, but should be long enough so that the notification gets truncated (or at least attempts to, as this is what causes the crash) at the foreign characters.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJLMSllzoLA

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you need a fix for this, use Siri or a Mac using iMessage to send yourself a new message. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204897

It's a three step procedure to recover and a future software update will patch this bug.

1. Ask Siri to "read unread messages."
2. Use Siri to reply to the malicious message. After you reply, you'll be able to open Messages again.
3. If the issue continues, tap and hold the malicious message, tap More, and delete the message from the thread.

---

As to why it happens, it's a specific bug in the way Notification Center renders the Unicode content of this message. The code performs an "unsafe" operation (something akin to 5 divided by 0 and then doesn't check for an unexpected results) that causes an unhandled error.

Then since Notification Center can not render the block of text and ultimately crashes the Springboard which didn't have code to handle this failure gracefully.
When no specific error handler is present, most operations have a fail safe "reboot yourself" to try and remedy the error.

[Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is a way of encoding characters used to handle languages that have a greater character count than English. Programmers can have problems with it because they learned to program using ASCII text and they neglect to write their software with full Unicode support.

One [good article on this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) explains "if you're still programming that way, you're not much better than a medical doctor who doesn't believe in germs".

This [other article](http://iphone.appleinsider.com/articles/15/05/26/bug-in-ios-notifications-handling-crashes-iphones-with-a-simple-text) explains this specific situation well.

Apple could either do tighter code reviews, have specific unit tests or let end users [fuzz test their code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) like in this and [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81019/why-does-file-crash-my-app) [cases](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157078/mail-crashes-when-i-open-a-specific-message).

Answer (score 6):

It is something for Apple to fix.

The problem appears to come from the way that the phone tries to show the message in notifications. The characters cause that system to break, so that it briefly tries to show it before crashing and then re-setting the phone in an attempt to fix it.

Here are some short term fixes you can do till Apple fixes the problem.

- Have the person who sent you the malicious message send another
  message effectively canceling out the initial strand
- Send yourself a message via Siri, the share sheet, or from your Mac.
- Another reader notes that “sending a photo to the contact via the Photos app can allow them to access the message history and
  delete the conversation”

<sub>source: http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-fix-ios-text-messages-crash-bug/</sub>